# WAS server application hungs When added c3p0 properties to hibernate

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling, c3p0

> [5/31/16 0:03:07:504 IST] 00000036 ThreadMonitor W   WSVR0605W: Thread
>   "WebContainer : 7" (00000032) has been active for 615004 milliseconds
>   and may be hung.  There is/are 1 thread(s) in total in the server that
>   may be hung.  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:196)    at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1414)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
>     at
>   com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:56)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:423)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:144)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1547)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:673)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1860)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:48)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:42)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3044)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:395)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:375)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:139)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:195)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:103)
>     at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:878)    at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:815)  at
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:808)  at
>   com.nexstep.travel.administrator.perdiemdomestic.dao.PerDiemDomesticMstDAO.validateTravelSettleAmtWithPerDiem(PerDiemDomesticMstDAO.java:727)
>     at
>   com.nexstep.travel.administrator.perdiemdomestic.service.PerDiemDomesticMasterBLOServiceImp.validateTravelSettleAmtWithPerDiem(PerDiemDomesticMasterBLOServiceImp.java:521)
>     at
>   com.nexstep.travel.administrator.perdiemdomestic.service.PerDiemDomesticMasterServiceImp.validateTravelSettleAmtWithPerDiem(PerDiemDomesticMasterServiceImp.java:261)
>     at
>   com.nexstep.framework.budgeting.ajaxutility.AjaxBudgetingUtility.validateTSAmtWithPerDiem(AjaxBudgetingUtility.java:5610)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1553.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599)     at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.ExecuteAjaxFilter.doFilter(ExecuteAjaxFilter.java:34)
>     at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter$1.doFilter(DefaultRemoter.java:428)
>     at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:431)
>     at
>   org.directwebremoting.impl.DefaultRemoter.execute(DefaultRemoter.java:283)
>     at
>   org.directwebremoting.servlet.PlainCallHandler.handle(PlainCallHandler.java:52)
>     at
>   org.directwebremoting.servlet.UrlProcessor.handle(UrlProcessor.java:101)
>     at
>   org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet.doPost(DwrServlet.java:146)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1443)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:790)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:175)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:859)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1557)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:173)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:272)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:202)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:766)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:896)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1527)

We get above exception when we have added c3p0 properties to the hibernate.cfg.xml , when we have tried commenting the c3p0 related properties, application works fine.

The properties that we have added in hibernate are as follows:

```
    <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ADMIN</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/TEST</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">ADMIN</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">3600</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

Can anybody tell us what we are missing that is causing here for connection leakages , Also the application hungs only at the production at our testing area the above properties works well.

Please suggest us that how can we resolve this issue.

Comment: To debug Connection leaks, please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_to_debug_and_workaround_broken_clients

Comment: you are right steve, but application currently at production environment we can not add debugging properties to it , and issue is not reproducing at our end . when we remove this c3p0 related properties our application works smoothly at production, we think we are missing some configurations thats why it is hunging the threads. can you please check configuration properties in hibernate.cfg.xml which we have added above.

Comment: max_statements is way too small for a pool that might have 100 Connections. you should just turn statement caching off (set that to zero) until you get the application working correctly, then experiment with statement caching for performance. but your issue is very likely a Connection leak. you either have to track it down in your application code (where do you sometimes fail to close Connections or Sessions?) or work around it (ugly) with `unreturnedConnectionTimeout`.

Comment: if we add unreturnedConnectionTimeout at application which cons we face .. Is it very harmful??

Comment: 1) leaked Connections are closed slowly, only after timing out, increasing the resource load (i.e. you keep more Connections open than you should); 2) your application remains unfixed (if you switch to a different pool, hangs will return, unless you find an analogous setting); 3) if `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` is set too short (to mitigate problem 1), or if some query takes uncommonly long, there is a danger that in-use Connections will get closed out from beneath the application.

Comment: Thanks Steve , We are thinking to set as you told max-statements = 0 and unreturnedConnectionTimeout = 600 to overcome the issue . I need your help in taking decision ... Is this right approach for production environment.??